# Gitlabhq gitolite update repos and keys issue

Tags: update, gitolite

I would like update gitolite. But when i start command

```
> sudo -u gitlab -H bundle exec rake gitlab:gitolite:update_repos

remote: Counting objects: 1459, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1172/1172), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (1459/1459), 133.14 KiB, done.
remote: Total 1459 (delta 462), reused 0 (delta 0)
Resolving deltas: 100% (462/462), done.
rake aborted!
gitolite timeout
/home/gitlab/gitlab/lib/gitlab/backend/gitolite_config.rb:77:in `rescue in apply'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/lib/gitlab/backend/gitolite_config.rb:24:in `apply'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/lib/gitlab/backend/gitolite_config.rb:118:in `update_project!'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/lib/gitlab/backend/gitolite.rb:26:in `update_repository'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/app/roles/repository.rb:108:in `update_repository'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/gitolite_rebuild.rake:8:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in find_each'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:21:in `each'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:21:in `block in find_each'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:72:in `find_in_batches'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:20:in `find_each'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/querying.rb:8:in `find_each'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/gitolite_rebuild.rake:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:gitolite:update_repos
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to [issue 1038](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1038):

> It's because `tmp` (`/home/gitlab/gitlab/tmp`) is missing, creating it should resolve the issue.